# Find out result size of unpacked archive without unpacking it. Or stop unpacking when certain size is exceed

Tags: python, linux, archive, 7zip, rar

I need to validate result size of unpacked archive without unpacking it, so that to prevent huge archives to store on my server. 
Or start unpacking and when size is exceeded certain size, then stop unpacking.
I have already tried lib `pyunpack`, but it allows only unpacking archives.
Need to validate such archive extensions:
`rar`, `zip`, `7z`, `tar`.
Maybe I can do it with using some linux features by calling them by `os.system`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a native python answer, but, if you need to fall back on `os.system`, the command-line utilities for handling all four formats have switches which can be used to list the contents of the archive including the size of each file and possibly a total size:

- `rar`: `unrar l FILENAME.rar` lists information on each file and the total size.
- `zip`: `unzip -l FILENAME.zip` lists size, timestamp, and name of each file, along with the total size.
- `7z`: `7z l FILENAME.7z` lists the details of each file and the total size.
- `tar`: `tar -tvf FILENAME.tar` or `tar -tvzf FILENAME.tgz` (or `.tar.gz`) lists details of each file including file size.  No total size is provided, so you'll need to add them up yourself.

If you're looking at native python libraries, you can also check for whether they have a "list" or "test" function.  Those are the terms used by the command-line tools to describe the switches I mentioned above, so the same names are likely to have been used by the library authors.

Answer (score 0):

A [zip file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) have a [infolist method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) which returns [zip info objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects). These zip info objects have a [file size](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.file_size) property which is the uncompressed size of the object. Just sum these sizes, and you're done.